# Calculus formula help for velocity

Tags: calculus

[image]

So I have this solution to a problem regarding velocity.  I cannot, for the life of me, figure out where the t= part came into play or what formula it is.  It look's really familiar but for some reason I am drawing a serious blank.  Could someone please help me with what is going on here?

Answer (score 2):

It is the quadratic formula, $$\text{For } ax^2+bx+c=0,\text{ the solution is } x=\frac{-b\pm\sqrt{b^2-4ac}}{2a}$$